# Getting a 401 Unauthorized Error when trying to access reports from the Google Alert Center API

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk, http-status-code-401, google-alert-center-api

I just had a query regarding a 401 Unauthorized error I seem to have run into while developing a script to pull reports from the Google Alert Center API. I am using the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/quickstart/java) with a service account and the applicable scope. I have also followed the guide and the credentials.json for the requisite service account seems to be correct as well.

This service account has already been granted [Domain Wide Delegation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJAwV.png) and permission to access the [SCOPES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu89d.png). I have also configured the service account to be [trusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3F72.png) in the API controls dashboard.
Here is the complete [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuXCv.png).

Just to be extra sure, I have also [added permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WICYx.png) for a user 'admin@xxxx.com' to use the service account as a resource.

Specifications:
Windows 10, Java 16, Eclipse IDE, Maven 3.6.3

Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong ?

Comment: My guess is that you are not impersonating a regular (admin) account, but just using the service account by itself. In order to clarify this, can you provide the authorization part of your code?

Comment: @lamblichus You are right !! I misunderstood the quickstart code and had set `private static final String DELEGATED_ADMIN_EMAIL = "admin@xxxx.com";` instead of an account with the proper permissions.

Comment: For documentation purposes, please consider posting an answer explaining what change you did to your code in order for it to work. Or I can provide a more conceptual answer, explaining the difference between enabling domain-wide delegation and actually impersonating an account.